# Splash / Launch Image getting stretched in landscape mode on iPhone

Tags: iphone, launch, splash-screen

I am facing an issue in my Application .

Splash / Launch Image getting stretched in landscape mode on iPhone

Right now while launching the Application in Landscape mode, the Launch Screen comes in Portrait mode and later after a few seconds,it changes to Landscape mode and then it gets stretched so only a part of the image is seen that also stretched.

Waiting for a favorable reply.

Thanks,

Jitendra Bhagat

Answer (score 0):

You need to use separate splash screen image for both the orientation.

For iPhone 6:
    750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
    1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

For iPhone 6 Plus:
    1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
    2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape